# Russian sanctions under Trump

Tags: united-states, russian-federation, sanctions

[NBC](https://www.nbcnews.com/politics/donald-trump/trump-administration-hit-russia-new-sanctions-skripal-poisoning-n898856?cid=sm_npd_nn_tw_ma) just announced President Trump was imposing additional sanctions upon Russia for the Skirpal poisoning incident in the UK.  These come on [top of sanction increases in April, 2018](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2018/apr/06/trump-russia-sanctions-election-meddling-latest)

> Senior Trump administration officials cast the penalties as part of a concerted and ongoing effort by the US to push back Putin’s government, emphasizing that since Trump took office last year, the US has punished 189 Russian-related people and entities with sanctions.

As the Guardian article shows, that set of sanctions was an escalation from some time earlier in Trump's presidency.  There may have been others

Q: Is there a timeline of all the sanctions President Trump has imposed upon Russia?  It would be kind of helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jun 20, 2017: ["Treasury Designates Individuals and Entities Involved in the Ongoing Conflict in Ukraine"](https://www.treasury.gov/press-center/press-releases/Pages/sm0114.aspx)

> The U.S. Department of the Treasury’s Office of Foreign Assets Control (OFAC) today reinforced existing sanctions on Russia by designating or identifying a range of individuals and entities involved in the ongoing conflict under four Executive orders (E.O.s) related to Russia and Ukraine.  Today’s action is designed to counter attempts to circumvent U.S. sanctions and will maintain alignment of U.S. measures with those of our international partners.  It will also provide additional information to assist the private sector with sanctions compliance.

Dec 20, 2017: [Issuance of Global Magnitsky Executive Order; Global Magnitsky Designations](https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/sanctions/OFAC-Enforcement/Pages/20171221.aspx)

(if you count this - its not really in the same vein as the others)

> The President has issued a new Executive Order on December 20, 2017 Blocking the Property of Persons Involved in Serious Human Rights Abuses and Corruption

Jan 26, 2018: ["Treasury Sanctions Additional Individuals and Entities in Connection with the Conflict in Ukraine and Russia’s Occupation of Crimea"](https://home.treasury.gov/news/press-releases/sm0266)

> The U.S. Department of the Treasury’s Office of Foreign Assets Control (OFAC) today designated 21 individuals and 9 entities under four Executive Orders (E.O.s) related to Russia and Ukraine, including three individuals and two entities related to Russia’s transfer of four turbines made by a Russian-German joint venture to Crimea.  Today’s action is part of Treasury’s continued commitment to maintain sanctions pressure on Russia until it fully implements its commitments under the Minsk agreements.  This action underscores the U.S. government’s opposition to Russia’s occupation of Crimea and firm refusal to recognize its attempted annexation of the peninsula.

Apr 6, 2018: ["Treasury Designates Russian Oligarchs, Officials, and Entities in Response to Worldwide Malign Activity"](https://home.treasury.gov/news/press-releases/sm0338)

> The U.S. Department of the Treasury’s Office of Foreign Assets Control (OFAC), in consultation with the Department of State, today designated seven Russian oligarchs and 12 companies they own or control, 17 senior Russian government officials, and a state-owned Russian weapons trading company and its subsidiary, a Russian bank.
>
> “The Russian government operates for the disproportionate benefit of
>   oligarchs and government elites,” said Treasury Secretary Steven T.
>   Mnuchin.  “The Russian government engages in a range of malign
>   activity around the globe, including continuing to occupy Crimea and
>   instigate violence in eastern Ukraine, supplying the Assad regime with
>   material and weaponry as they bomb their own civilians, attempting to
>   subvert Western democracies, and malicious cyber activities.  Russian
>   oligarchs and elites who profit from this corrupt system will no
>   longer be insulated from the consequences of their government’s
>   destabilizing activities.”

Aug 8, 2018: ["Imposition of Chemical and Biological Weapons Control and Warfare Elimination Act Sanctions on Russia"](https://www.state.gov/r/pa/prs/ps/2018/08/285043.htm)

> Following the use of a “Novichok” nerve agent in an attempt to assassinate UK citizen Sergei Skripal and his daughter Yulia Skripal, the United States, on August 6, 2018, determined under the Chemical and Biological Weapons Control and Warfare Elimination Act of 1991 (CBW Act) that the Government of the Russian Federation has used chemical or biological weapons in violation of international law or has used lethal chemical or biological weapons against its own nationals.

Source was crawling backwards through the [Enigma US Sanctions tracker](https://labs.enigma.com/sanctions-tracker/)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.